# Autogenerate Swagger file from Node.js Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger

Has some one used any package that help generating Swagger file from lambda function (node.js) code?
One of the reqt is package sld also help define authorizer in swagger file.

purpose is  to auto generate  API gateways with authorizer configured by importing that swagger file?

Pl. guide if someone has any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , Checked the link!! Not able to make out if anything wrong about my question. Please specify!!

Comment: You should provide the details of your problem and minimal reproducible sample. Please check these links as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask